# How to create a glossary page in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views

I tried to create glossary page like [this](https://www.drupal.org/glossary). I've used [Glossary](https://www.drupal.org/project/glossary) module version 7.x-1.x-dev.

But i couldn't make it work. How to create glossary page in Drupal 7?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided is on [the list of things you are not allowed to ask here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Install https://www.drupal.org/project/views module. Go to Structure > Views, then enable the 'Glossary' view. View module provide 'Glossary' view by default.

Option 2: Also you can achieve your requirements by installing https://www.drupal.org/project/views_glossary module.

Comment: It is not i wanted. Please view given url above. I wanted like that url.

Answer (score 2):

Here are quite some contributed modules for creating a glossary in a D7 site (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Lexicon](http://drupal.org/project/lexicon):

  > A lexicon is a stock of terms used in a particular profession, subject or style; a vocabulary. The Lexicon module generates one or more Lexicon pages based on terms in taxonomies and optionally marks terms in the content and links them to the appropriate Lexicon page.
  >
  > The Lexicon module started out as a fork of the Glossary module project that was changed to suit the needs of a project for the Dutch government and later ported to Drupal 7. The main reason for forking the Glossary module was compliancy with the web guidelines of the Dutch government.
- [Glossify](http://drupal.org/project/glossify):

  > The Glossify module provides filters that scan and parse content and replace terms in the text with links to their pages. The d7 version is a complete rewrite of the module to be as simple and performant as possible.
- [G2](http://drupal.org/project/g2):

  > Glossary2 (G2) is an alternative glossary module written for Drupal 4.7 to 7.0, designed for high-volume glossary / dictionary sites.
- [Glossary](http://drupal.org/project/glossary):

  > The Glossary module helps newbies understand the jargon which always crops up when specialists talk about a topic. Doctors discuss CBC and EKG and CCs. Web developers keep talking about CSS, P2P, XSLT, etc. This is all intimidating for newbies.
  >
  > The glossary module scans posts for glossary terms (including synonyms). The glossary indicator is inserted after every found term, or the term itself is turned into an indicator depending on the site settings. By hovering over the indicator, users may learn the definition of that term. Clicking the indicator leads the user to that term presented within the whole glossary or directly to the detailed description of the term, if available.
  >
  > The glossary uses Drupal's built in taxonomy feature, so you can organize your terms in a Drupal vocabulary. This allows you to create hierarchical structures, synonyms and relations. Glossary terms are represented with the taxonomy terms in the glossary vocabulary. Descriptions are used to provide a short explanation of the terms. You can attach nodes to the terms to provide detailed explanation on the keywords.

Refer to [Comparison of Glossary-type modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/266511) for lots of information about these modules.

Comment: I've used all above modules. but i can't get it work as expected